# What happens when a Lucene index is split using IndexSplitter while it is being written or segments are being merged

Tags: split, lucene

I have a large lucene 9.5.0 index with multiple segments created. It is being actively written every few hours. I want to split this index into multiple indexes using Lucene's IndexSplitter command line tool as the number of documents in this index are reaching 2.14 billion which is the hard limit in lucene.
Will this splitting cause any consistency issues or data corruption if the index is being written actively? Although, the segments are not modified once written in Lucene, it might be merging segments during auto optimization that it does. Can splitting the index during that merge process cause any data corruption?

I have tried to split a test index and that seemed to be working fine. But I am not sure when does this auto-merge happens.